# Как при помощи регулярного выражения убрать первую строку

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как возможно убрать первую строку из текста при помощи регулярного выражения, например:

Сам текст: "Первая строка\n Нужная строка"

В результате:

```
Первая строка
Нужная строка
```

Пример в коде:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String t = "Первая строка\nНужная строка";
        System.out.println(t.split("\n")[1]); // Вернёт исключение, если не будет в тексте '\n'. 
    }
}
```

При помощи split[] не подходит, т.к. выбрасывается исключение если текст будет состоять только из 1 строки. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: `т.к. выбрасывается исключение` код и текст исключения в студию

Comment: @tym32167, если первой строки не будет, тогда ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: если первой строки нет, то и второй нет. то есть строка пустая.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос минимальный воспроизводим пример

Comment: @DarthKYL, добавил со split'ом

Comment: так вам нужна сторая строка или убрать первую?

Comment: @tym32167, если в тексте 2 строки, тогда убрать первую и вернуть вторую. Если в тексте 1 строка,  тогда ничего не убирать, а вернуть сам текст

Comment: а если 5 строк?

Comment: `System.out.println(t.contains("\n") ? t.split("\n")[1] : t);` ?

Comment: @tym32167, да, такой вариант подходит. Просто хотел проверить это с регуляркой. К примеру, replaceAll (до '\n', "$1").

Comment: хз сработает или нет, но может тогда `System.out.println(t.replaceAll("^.+\n", ""));` ?

Comment: @tym32167, да, это сработает если в тексте '\n' есть. Я возьму тот вариант твой выше с тернарным оператором. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант номер раз

```
System.out.println(t.contains("\n") ? t.split("\n")[1] : t);
```

Вариант номер два

```
System.out.println(t.replaceAll("^.+\n", ""));
```

Enterprise вариант

```
public static String skipFirstLine(String input){
     if (input == null) return null;
     String[] lines = input.split("\n");
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i=1; i<lines.length; i++) sb.append(lines[i]);
     return sb.toString();
}
```